# How to download all documents including the documents from folder also from SharePoint library to a physical location on desktop and rename them

Tags: 2010, document-library, powershell, download

I have 10,000 documents in SharePoint 2010 library. Is there any PowerShell script which will download all documents from SharePoint document library but I won't need the folder structure to be downloaded, all the documents from the sub-folders also should be downloaded to one physical location and rename all documents with some 'prefix' while downloading to physical location.

Answer (score 3):

I have modified the script from this [URL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varun_malhotra/2012/02/08/sharepoint-2010-powershell-download-all-files-in-document-library-to-network-share-file-share/) to adjust with your requirements

```
######################## Start Variables ########################
######################## Varun's Script######################
$destination = "C:\\tools\\Folder"
$webUrl = "<Url of the specific site>"
$listUrl = "<Url of the specific list. This url is complete Url and NOT relative url>"
##############################################################

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl
$list = $web.GetList($listUrl)

function ProcessFolder {
    param($folderUrl)
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
        #Ensure destination directory
        $destinationfolder = $destination

        #Download file
        $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "\PREFIX_" + $file.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
    }
}

#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download files in folders
foreach ($folder in $list.Folders) {
    ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but the above script will download with entire folder structure but is there any way by which I can flatten folders also.

Comment: I have made the script to flatten the files.. have you tried the above script i have posted?

Comment: Yes , I have tried but the output is like below.

Comment: Folder1 ->file1 ->Folder2 ->file2 but i need as Folder1->file1->file2

Comment: It's giving error for this line any solution?  $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "\PREFIX_" + $file.Name), Create