# Data migration from SharePoint to LAN Share Folders

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, migration, content-migration

User wants to migrate 40 GB of data from SharePoint 2013 team site to a LAN Share Folder

Would I be able to migrate the data this way using DocAve? I know it's possible to migrate data from LAN Share to SharePoint. Not sure about different ways to migrate large content from SharePoint to LAN Shares

Comment: Why dont you just open the library in open with explorer option in IE and migrate?

Comment: I can do that. However, it would take a lot of time. Any possible alternatives to bulk migrate the data?

Comment: 3rd party software, like DocAve, Sharegate, Metalogix, yata yata. I would go with Sharegate as it's the cheapest and will get the job done, you get a 15 day trial. Disclaimer: I use the software but have no relation with the company.

Answer (score 1):

there are couple of different ways to do.

- open with explorer
- Another method is map the document library with local drive, then move the files to local drive. [check this link](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/09/06/map-sharepoint-libraries-with-local-file-drive-a-step-by-step-guide/) of [this link](https://www.fpweb.net/blog/transferring-files-with-sharepoint-using-network-places-drives/)
- If you are copying the docs from onedriveforbussiness then [follow this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Download-files-and-folders-from-OneDrive-or-SharePoint-5c7397b7-19c7-4893-84fe-d02e8fa5df05)
- write some script to download all files. check this [How to download all documents including the documents from folder also from SharePoint library to a physical location on desktop and rename them](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186730/how-to-download-all-documents-including-the-documents-from-folder-also-from-shar)

Comment: As per Waqas his methods works for me https://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/09/06/map-sharepoint-libraries-with-local-file-drive-a-step-by-step-guide/